# how to get frequency of different lists, in list of lists

Tags: r

Suppose i have the following list:

```
test<-list(c("a","b","c"),c("a,c"),c("a,c"),c("a","b","c"),c("a"))
```

I want this as result:

```
("a","b","c") = 2
("a,c")=2
("a")=1
```

I tried with

```
> table(test)
Error in table(test) : all arguments must have the same length
```

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Why don't you post as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a one-liner. The upper row of numbers are the vector's names.

```
table(match(test, unique(test)))
#1 2 3 
#2 2 1
```

---

### Edit

A suggestion of @Ritchie Sacramento in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69630475/how-to-get-frequency-of-different-lists-in-list-of-lists?noredirect=1#comment123076201_69630475) is to change the names of the output above with

```
setNames(table(match(test, unique(test))), sapply(unique(test), toString))
#a, b, c     a,c       a 
#      2       2       1
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with `sapply` and `toString`:

```
> table(sapply(test, toString))

      a a, b, c     a,c 
      1       2       2 
>
```